# Creating CocoaPod for existing GitHub repo

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

Recently I've created small iOS class and I would like to use it with CocoaPods. By now I have added it to the [GitHub](https://github.com/cloverstudio/CSGrowingTextView) and I have followed [this tutorial](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/28-creating-a-cocoapod) which explains the process of creating CocoaPod but I have stuck with this one: "Adding the Podspec to the CocoaPods Specs Repo".

Can someone explain following steps, like how to fork the repository and issue a pull request.
I know there are a lot of similar answers on Google but I would be very appreciative if someone can share it's experience with creating CocoaPods.

Also is there an option for checking what will be final result when I add pod to my project before I make it public?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You now need to use [Trunk](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/) to upload your spec. Firstly, ensure you have registered a session with Trunk:

```
pod trunk register [email] [name] --description=[your session description]
```

1. `pod spec create`
2. Edit the `SuperAwesomeProject.podspec` file and save. [Podspec Syntax Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)
3. Run `pod spec lint` and fix any errors it reports.
4. Deploy your podspec with `pod trunk push SuperAwesomeProject.podspec`

Much simpler than the old method below!

**Note: The information posted below is now outdated.**

---

**DO NOT DO THIS.** I'm just leaving it here for posterity..

1. Visit [CocoaPods Specs Repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/)
2. Press Fork and choose your GitHub account.
3. Clone your repo using Terminal `git clone git@github.com:github-username/Specs.git`
4. `cd Specs && mkdir -p project-name/version-number` e.g. `mkdir -p SuperAwesomeProject/0.0.1`
5. `cd SuperAwesomeProject/0.0.1`
6. `pod spec create`
7. Edit the `SuperAwesomeProject.podspec` file and save. [Podspec Syntax Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)
8. Run `pod spec lint` and fix any errors it reports.
9. If your spec passes linting, add your podspec with `git commit -am "Added SuperAwesomeProject"`
10. `git push origin master`
11. Visit your GitHub fork page and submit a [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)
12. Wait for one of the Spec owners to merge your pull request.

If you already have a podspec file, just copy it into the `SuperAwesomeProject/0.0.1` folder and skip step 7.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, my answer is too late... Anyway, please find below steps that I've performed:

1. pod trunk register YOUR_EMAIL 'YOUR_NAME' --description='YOUR_MAC'
2. pod spec create YOUR_LIBRARY YOUR_GITHUB_LIBRARY_URL
3. edit YOUR_LIBRARY.podspec
4. pod spec lint
5. pod trunk push YOUR_LIBRARY.podspec