# Create cocoapod from existing project hosted Github (and locally)

Tags: objective-c, git, github, cocoapods

Some weeks ago I've created an interactive transition in Objective-C.
I've created a repository on GitHub and I've hosted a project which contains the transition classes and the example code to handle it.
My routine is the following:

1. Make changes locally in Xcode
2. Commit them
3. Push them to the remote repository on GitHub
4. Review Pull request

Now many user ask me to integrate the transition with CocoaPods.
Personally I love CocoaPods and I integrate it in all my project, but I don't have made any cocoapod yet.
I've read the [official guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/index.html) and tutorial like [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332), but these are about project from scratch.
I'm wondering how to integrate the cocoapods template (Example + pod) with my existing project on GitHub (and locally).
I know there is the command `pod lib create COCOAPOD_NAME` , but it create a template (Example + pod) from the scratch that it is not sync with the repository on GitHub.

I''ve also read this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22686958/5147193), but this is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want create pod from existing project it's very simple :-)
I also make it the other day.

Firstly you need create podspec and fill with your information (also don't forget add license, it's very important).

Secondly just follow the instructions [like this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html#deploying-your-library)

After your podspec will be success you need push it all in trunk ([it's very simple](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk.html))

Maybe you help my lib (.travis don't need in start)
[SimpleKit](https://github.com/ajjnix/SimpleKit)

Comment: Your lib is not available. I still can't find solution.